# Java File I/O seems to stop working after program runs a while - no errors

Tags: java, windows

I've tried both File.listFiles() and Guava's Files.fileTreeTraverser().breadthFirstTraversal(dir).

```
    if (dir.exists()) {
        for (File f : Files.fileTreeTraverser().breadthFirstTraversal(dir)) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                if (f.getName().endsWith(EXT)) {
                    matches.add(f);
                } else {
                    if (!f.getName().endsWith(".ini")) {
                        log.db("No match: " + f.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.error("No directory found.");
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    log.db(matches);
```

In both of these cases, after the program runs for a while (running this particular code 2x a second), matches turns empty. For Guava, there's no error at all. For Java's File.listFiles(), dir.listFiles() becomes null.

This code runs on Windows and doesn't do anything else to the directory apart from occasionally writing a file. There is only 1 file in the directory.

Is there some rule in Windows that causes file i/o to stop working after a while?

Comment: Just a guess in the blue: Did you open this file several times without properly closing it after that?

Comment: Where are you calling File.listFiles()? And no there is no such rule.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher, I'm not opening it, only getting the file names and deleting & creating files. No input or output streams are opened.

Comment: @Oleg File.listFiles() used to be where the current fileTreeTraverser() is, my point is I've tried both but the most recent one I tried is what I showed (Guava).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was that some of my other code, which used JNA (incorrectly), was failing to properly release file handles. So eventually the JVM ran out of handles to give and was unable to list files anymore.